# Dynamo DB - Index using Composite Sort Key not working apparently

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to DynamoDB and just trying out certain things.
Tried making composite sort key inside a GSI, but it is not working as a regular sort key should.

I am designing a Notifications system; my table includes attributes like customerId, read("TRUE" or "FALSE"), createdAt, notificationId, etc.

My base table is composed of **customerId** as the partition key and **createdAt** as the sort key.
But I have another access pattern, I need to retrieve all read/unread notifications for a single customer in descending order of **createdAt**.
So, I tried to make a GSI with **customerId** as the partition key and a composite sort key of **read#createdAt** with hopes that it would give me all read/unread notifications sorted by date. But the problem is that I don't get any items inside of that index table.

However, creating an index table with **customerId** as partition key and just **read** as sort key works, which tells me that something must be wrong when creating the composite sort key.

```
"GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
    {
        IndexName: "customerId-read-createdAt-index",
        KeySchema: [
            { AttributeName: "customerId", KeyType: "HASH" },
            { AttributeName: "read#createdAt", KeyType: "RANGE" },
        ],
        Projection: { ProjectionType: "ALL" },
        BillingMode: "PAY_PER_REQUEST",
    }
]
```

Attribute Definitions in the table are:

```
"AttributeDefinitions": [
        {
            "AttributeName": "customerId",
            "AttributeType": "N"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "read",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "read#createdAt",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

My naieve assumption here is that you expect DynamoDB to combine two individual attributes to create your composite sort key for you...

If you want a composite key of `read#createdAt` then a an attribute of that name must exist in the tables items, otherwise no data will be projected to your index.

Comment: And must be populated by whatever is writing to DDB.